# API для superjob

Tags: api, r, парсер

Добрый день.
Использую парсер на R для сбора данных с работных сайтов. Намедни по некоторым ссылкам парсинг стал происходить крайне медленное, реально очень медленно. За хожу по ссылка сайта с которых собираю данные иногда выдаёт ошибку 503.
Переписка с тех. поддержкой суперджоба в итоге сообщила такой результат

"Ваш парсер по запросам к сайту, попадает под условия нашей защиты от ботов и поэтому временно возникает 503 ошибка, если есть возможность то попробуйте использовать наше API"

Документация здесь https://api.superjob.ru/

Подскажите какой пакет(ы) лучше всего использовать для авторизации к API сайта?
Возможно существуют другие решения?

API с авторизацией.

Работаю в fedora24 X64

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендую пакет `request`. Это по сути «обёртка» над `httr`, но предлагает удобный синтаксис и некоторые дополнительные возможности.